# Web API 2 in distinct layer

Tags: architecture, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

Im in the planning phase of an Web App and I hope some advices.

Im drawing a DAL and Web MVC 5 in distinct layers and I know that this project will require some integration with another systems.

My question is:

Should be good to create an Web API 2 layer between DAL and Web MVC 5?

The main pourpose here is to centralize the data access format and minimize future maintenances.

Comment: What do you mean by DISTINCT layer? What kind of integration with another systems do you expect? Just through Web API, right?

Comment: For the first question I do mean that DAL and Web MVC 5 are in separate projects. For the third one is YES.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both Web API and Web MVC layers are parts of logical presentation layer and usually they stand next to each other and are not mixed. Here's just a few disadvatages of the approach from the top of my head:

1. Performance - a redundant HTTP roundtrip in Web MVC project.
2. Separation of concerns - most of the time the functionality provided by API differs greatly form UI for the same project/application. You might want to limit the API to a few methods with a strict contract. In case you want Web API to be a layer between Web MVC and your DAL you will have to expose all functionality you need for UI as well. Also you might want to have different authorization and authentication mechanisms. Very often API exceptions handling is also different as well as input validation.
3. Maintanance - everytime you need to make a change required for UI only you have to make sure it doesn't brake your API clients. Also API versioning is a very important topic and mixing it with most UI changes makes this process even more difficult.

You can read up on contract versioning here - [Versioning Strategies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff384251.aspx)

If I were you I would make both Web API and Web MVC layers as thin as possible, as they should be in perfect world. Then add a Business Layer and use it both in Web API and Web MVC. The Business Layer should encapsulate all common logic you want to cetralize and reduce maintanance for. So it should be

DAL -> Business Layer -> Web API

and

DAL -> Business Layer -> Web MVC

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have some difficulties to define what is my Business Layer. I need a dummy example :(

Comment: Im only work with stored procedures to manipulate my data and LINQ to Entities to select.

Comment: Sure. Consider your application is a web shop and when a user makes an order you should do a few queries to make sure the products are still available then save the order to db and send a user an email with the order id. So these three actions should be put into a business layer service. You might have OrderService with a method CreateOrder. Then inside this method you call your DAL to do validation queries and save the order entity. Then there's should be a call to an smpt server to send the email. The three actions are the business logic and should always go together when creating an order

Comment: Very clear. Can my models (also ViewModels) be in business layer?

Comment: No, view models should be in the presentation layer only which is either Web API or Web MVC in your case and you should have a mapping between your business entities and view models in the Web API or MVC controller. So you might have Order business entity to return from your CreateOrder method. Then you have a view model OrderViewModel. Please note you might have different view models for API and UI. Then in API/MVC controller you do mapping between Order and OrdeViewModel and pass the view model to a view or as a Web API result. Personally I prefer Automapper to do the mappings stuff.